# Django more than one ListView to an html page

Tags: html, django, listview, web, django-queryset

I am looking to be able to access both `post_list10`, and `photo_list` on my blog.html however I am only able to access one when it is written like this. Does anyone know how to write it so I can access both?

```
post_list10 = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10]
photo_list = Photo.objects.all()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

                       url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
                           queryset=post_list10,
                           template_name="blog.html")),

                       # FOR SOME REASON WHICHEVER COMES FIRST TAKES PRECEDENT. Cannot do both.

                       url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
                           queryset=photo_list,
                           template_name="blog.html")))
```

Also,

when calling the list in my blog.html I can use

```
{% for post in object_list %} 
.....

{% endfor %}
```

in order to work with the available post objects but how do I know if I'm working with posts or photos if I can access both? Sorry if my wording is unclear, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: I'd imagine that you need to write your own view to do this. Then call that view from the URLs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that or point me to a clear documentation? I've read about them but at the time I didn't quite follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to solve your problem would usually involve writing your own view.
A simple way of doing this is as follows:

in urls.py:

```
from views import my_view

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', my_view, name="my_blog"),
)
```

in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

def my_view(request):
    """The view for your blog page"""
    post_list10 = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10]
    photo_list = Photo.objects.all()

    template = loader.get_template('blog.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,{
        'post_list': post_list10,
        'photo_list': photo_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The the template in blog.html would be changed to this:

```
{% for post in post_list %} 
.....

{% endfor %}

{% for photo in photo_list %} 
.....

{% endfor %}
```

Another thing I noticed is this comment "# FOR SOME REASON WHICHEVER COMES FIRST TAKES PRECEDENT. Cannot do both.". This is indeed the correct, and desired, behavior. The way the URL matching works is that Django starts at the top of the of the URL patterns and then iterates through. The first regex match that is found for the URL in the request is the one that is used and no further searching takes place. Because you had the same regex `^$` for both only the first one in the `urlpatterns` would ever be matched. This behavior will happen every time you have a duplicated regex, the second one just never gets used.

Generally speaking the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com) is very high quality, so do read that if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it definitely helped me understand the documentation better using my own example. I have another question if that is alright.

If I've got different parts of a website that contain different posts, e.g. Discussion about basketball, and Discussion about football, if I wanted to return just posts concerning basketball or just posts concerning football, is the easiest way to just make a specific basketball_post model/football_post model?

Comment: @user3853339, glad this helped. Generally speaking the idea behind StackOverflow is to ask one question at a time, so make a new question about the discussion topic filtering and I'll go and answer that over there. Also, if answers solve your problem on this site you might like to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the question.